# Full page not printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

Thats my printpage Event Handler Code

```
private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int yaxis = 0;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Store Inventory Report", font, Brushes.Black, 0, yaxis);
        yaxis += 30;
    }
}
```

This code only prints line 37 times. . . its not printing full page. . i generates its pdf, pdf also have line 37 times.

[image]

Comment: Did you specify a page size?

Comment: Have you checked whether the printing area when sending to actual printer? The printable margin might be different with the pdf version. Try to change the `Font` size or `yaxis` to see if your printing outside printable area.

Comment: @Jcl No i didtnt specify the size. . .i want all 300 lines on 1 page so i could print this on thermal printer

Comment: You need to either set up the page height to allow for holding your 300 lines, or print many pages with the amount of lines that fit in one each time (and setting `e.HasMorePages` to true on your `PrintPage` event)

Comment: @Jcl hot to set the page height ? i am printing it on roll paper

Comment: @Mateen-ul-haq should be on the `PrintDocument` (`DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize`). For the screenshot you put, it seems to me that it's indeed printing all 300 lines, just on the first page (and it gets cropped because it's printing out of bounds). `PaperSize` should be a `PaperSize` object, something like `new PaperSize("My Custom Size", width, height)`, width and height expressed in hundredths of an inch. Try setting a very large height and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **full printing** did you mean printing all the 300 lines base on your code? If it is you should set the parameter:

```
 e.HasMorePages = true;
```

Set it to false when you reach the condition where all contents are already printed.

For your case it would be something like this:

```
private int startIndex = 0; //Keeps track of printed index
private int limit = 300; //Limit of items to print

private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    int yaxis = 0;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
    for (int i = startIndex; i < limit; i++)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Store Inventory Report", font, Brushes.Black, 0, yaxis);
        yaxis += 30;

        //Reaches bottom? break the loop
        if (yaxis > e.PageBounds.Bottom)
        {
            startIndex = i + 1; //Set to next page's data index 
            break;
        }
    }

    //Still has pages?
    e.HasMorePages = startIndex < limit; 

}
```

Comment: still same problem. . .i just want all 300 lines on one page. . .so i can print it on themaal printer

Comment: So you mean 300 lines on one page? Well you have to limit the `font size` and vertical spacing in your case to fit 300 items.

Comment: Hi @Mateen-ul-haq, have you resolved this issue?. I am facing same issues in thermal printer. Can you suggest a solution for this?